# Hide html div element in the weekend and shown on working days

Tags: javascript, if-statement, hide, show

I use the following code to disable a Whatsapp icon after 5 o'clock on working days:

```
var d = new Date();
if(d.getHours() >= 7 && d.getHours() <= 12 ){
    $(".open").show();
    $(".closed").hide();
}
else {  
     $(".closed").show();
    $(".open").hide();
}
```

Now we want also that the whatsapp icon will be disabled / hide in the weekend. Can anybody help me updating the if / else condition? Many thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```js
const today = new Date();
const dayOfWeek = today.getDay();

const isWeekend = (dayOfWeek === 6) || (dayOfWeek  === 0);

if(isWeekend){
  console.log('hide Weekend div');
}else{
  console.log('show Weekend div');
}
```

Comment: Thanks I wil check tomorrow after 830u what will happen when I add the 'open' and 'closed' classes for the 'isWeekend' condition. I will let you know!

Comment: My current code worked. the "closed" class has a display none after 17pm and will hide the div but I'm not sure how I can test your code outside the weekend. I've add it under my code.

Comment: You can insert a custom date inside the date object. For example const todays = new Date('Thu Aug 20 2022 20:16:40');